# Long PCB breadboard

Tags: pcb, breadboard, prototyping

I'm looking for a PCB breadboard longer than this one:

[image]

I spent a long while searching without success. Any clues or confirmation of futility of further search would be greatly appreciated.

---

Here is a perfect solution for my application, more versatile than PCB breadboard:

[image]

This board can be separated along scored lines.

Comment: this seems dangerously close to a shopping question.

Comment: @Jasen Thanks. I kept looking and got rewarded with more formats - long or side by side: https://www.amazon.com/ElectroCookie-Solderable-Breadboards-Gold-Plated-Multi-Pack/dp/B07ZV9JQY2

Comment: Try just building on one of the many protoboards that do not follow the solderless breadboard format. Not only do they come in more sizes, but when you aren't limited to the solderless breadboard format you can also pack a lot more in since you can use every hole if you wanted to.

Comment: @DKNguyen Luckily, I found a strip board, which is more versatile for my need (see added image). I rejected perfboards (unconnected holes), because they take more time wiring.

Comment: Could you just make your own?

Comment: @Hearth Too much hassle for one-off project. I can wire a prototype board faster and cheaper than designing a PCB. Also, design changes are much easier and faster.

Comment: @PaulJurczak But designing and having a few dozen copies of an extra-large breadboard-style protoboard manufactured surely wouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: @Hearth I would spend weeks just trying to find the most versatile and optimal design. Buying is easier. Too many projects, too little time...

Comment: @PaulJurczak My suggestion is just to do a plain breadboard layout, identical to the boards you're looking to buy but unable to find. Not a custom layout.

Comment: @Hearth Oh, but I already found them - see my first comment above.

Answer (score 2):

There are some PCB fabricators who could provide boards like this to your exact specifications for only a few dollars.

Answer (score 1):

These exist. Do an image search on the phrase `PCB breadboard`.

Answer (score 1):

They do exist. Product recommendations are *not done* here, but you may want to search for "large solderable breadboard".

There's even one that is open-source hardware and fully documented, including schematic and Eagle files on [GitHub](https://github.com/sparkfun/Solderable_Breadboard_Large), so you could have a batch made yourself, or even adapt it to your needs before you do.

*<sub>Disclaimer: It is not my fault if you happen to stumble across the manufacturer's name on GitHub.</sub>*